Nsis Cpack как можно сделать проверку запущен ли тихий установщик или с интерфейс ом?
Пробовал делать так, но это не работает. Приложение по какой-то причине всё равно запускается, вне зависимости от варианта запуска установщика.
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS "
  !ifdef SILENT
       Exec '$INSTDIR\\TerminalsThisWay.exe'
       MessageBox MB_OK 'TerminalsThisWay is not currently running.'
  !endif
") 


Я уже нашел ответ самостоятельно, напишу его здесь на тот случай, если у кого-то возникнет такая же проблема:
IfSilent +2
GoTo NotSilent
Exec '$INSTDIR\\TerminalsThisWay.exe'
NotSilent:

